# calling a soap webservice from android

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to call a web service from android. The code is working fine with no errors but I get no output. I am new to android. Please help me out.

The whole tutorial is [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/) ....

There are three buttons <kbd>clear button</kbd> do well but both <kbd>convert to celsius</kbd> and <kbd>convert to fahrenheit</kbd> don't work. 
Actually there is the statement in both of them in the try block

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

I guess at this line the application get stuck because I put the builder message after each statement it prompted but after this statement it did not .
Please tell me what is the problem, I am really worried..

Comment: 1st try to debug your code and check is this line that causing error 
then Read Error 
and then Post your Logcat trace/stack trace here

Answer (score 0):

try to use this class to call a web service:

```
public class WSRequest {

    public HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport;
    public SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope; 
    public String methodName;
    public SoapObject request;

    public WSRequest(String methodName)
    {
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.request = new SoapObject(SRWebServer.NAMESPACE, methodName);
        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SRWebServer.URL);
    }

    public void RegisterMarshal()
    {
        MarshalBase64 marshal = new MarshalBase64();
        marshal.register(envelope);
    }

    public SoapObject Send() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException 
    {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        new MarshalDate().register(envelope);
        this.androidHttpTransport.call(SRWebServer.NAMESPACE + this.methodName, envelope);
        return (SoapObject) this.envelope.getResponse();
    }



    public void AddProperties(String name, Object value)
    {
        this.request.addProperty(name, value);

    }
        // 

}
```

and use this way:

```
WSRequest request =  new WSRequest("method name here");
request.addProperties("property1Name",property1);
request.Send();
```

`requestSend()` will return a SoapObject containing the object received from the web service.

Comment: i have tried this code but after running this the applications gets stuck and closed autometically;(

Comment: use debug to see where it crashes,and post a log cat.I use this class to call web services and it works perfectly.